# collectstaic command fails gives me post-processing error

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku, deployment

While deploying my django-app to heroku I get this error .I disabled collectstatic and it pushed but when I went to the site it wasn't working.I tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work

```
Post-processing 'vendors/owl-carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css' failed!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 188, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 134, in collect
    raise processed
whitenoise.storage.MissingFileError: The file 'vendors/owl-carousel/assets/owl.video.play.png' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7f580a2b32e8>.

The CSS file 'vendors/owl-carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css' references a file which could not be found:
  vendors/owl-carousel/assets/owl.video.play.png

Please check the URL references in this CSS file, particularly any
relative paths which might be pointing to the wrong location.
```

my settings.py looks like this

```
"""
Django settings for personal_portfolio project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""
import django_heroku
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'y5hmuk*-4*%wor)ek2up+w+x!yx8l40j*n93#1zn!p66)k=c#2'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',

    'blog',
    'portfolio'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'personal_portfolio.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'personal_portfolio.custom_context.blog_context',
                'personal_portfolio.custom_context.portfolio_context',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'personal_portfolio.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
#         'NAME': 'portfolio_db',
#         'USER': 'sajib1066',
#         'PASSWORD': 'sajib1099',
#         'HOST': 'localhost',
#         'PORT': '',
#     }
# }

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

# static files
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

# media files

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': None,
    },
}


# Activate Django-Heroku.
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

I tried a lot for it to work but I am not able to figure out what's wrong.Please help!

Answer (score 0):

it is because you haven't put any specified static root location that is the reason do one thing add this in your settings.py in the end and try again thats it

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
```

Comment: do one thing run command after adding static root file and after that run cmd command "python manage.py collectstatic" after that make debug=True and after that run the project and cross check you can get that error css file in template 'vendors/owl-carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css' references a file which could not be found:
  vendors/owl-carousel/assets/owl.video.play.png"